# Show background image in div without content

Tags: html, css

I simply have a div with a background image. The image only shows if I set min-height, or if i set the height of the div

**HTML**

```
<div class='mydiv'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mydiv{          
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
    background-size:contain ;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;  

}
```

This is the jsfiddle link for above
http://jsfiddle.net/L4pyhjeu/

I am actually using bootstrap 3 to create a div . The problem I have with setting a min height is that at the desktop width the image shows fine, but when shrunk down to mobile, it becomes too tall  at my min-height:550px.

**So the idea is that if the min-height is not set, the image will show at its own 100% height width which looks fine on both desktop and mobile.**

I tried & nbsp ; in the div but that didnt work, i also tried block display - that doesn't show the image either.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why not use a media query to change the height when you get to a small screen size?

Comment: If your div is empty then it has no height so you will not see the background image. Use media query to set appropriate width/height

Comment: thankx, well yes I thought of media query but I wondered if there was a way I could avoid using those it would be nicer

Comment: You can use media queries, use an img tag instead of background or use JS. It's the only ways I can think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution is to add a media query. For example, add this in your CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .mydiv {
    min-height:250px;
    /*etc*/
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, so i think I'll have to use media queries, there isn't any other quick way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You must check if the website is being rendered on a mobile device or a desktop. For a mobile site, you can set height in percentage. For a PC, you can set it in pixels.